# Using url unescape to build a url within a view in a string

Tags: ruby, url

I am building a url in a view within my sinatra app

I required the URI module in my app.

```
<li><a href="/blog/#{URI.unescape(<%= blog.title %>)}/<%= blog.slug %>"" method="get">Show</a></li>
```

Without `URI.unescape` I do not see `%20` when I hover over the link. I just see this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9292/blog/Coffee Title/49459
```

I am hoping for that space to be a `-`. But when I click on the link it will return in my browser as:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9292/blog/Coffee%20Title/49459
```

I tried using `URI.unescape` in irb. I am having trouble evaluating the Ruby code within the string. I am not sure what the right format is but think I am getting close.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the space is percent-encoded in the actual HTML the server is sending to your browser, or are you just seeing the `%20` when you hover or click on the link?

Comment: Without `URI.unescape` I do not see `%20` when I hover over the link. I just see this `http://127.0.0.1:9292/blog/Coffee Title/49459`. I am hoping for that space to be a `-`. But when I click on the link it will return in my browser as `http://127.0.0.1:9292/blog/Coffee%20Title/49459`.

Comment: You didn't mention that you want to replace spaces with dashes. You should edit your question to describe exactly what output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URI.escape` replaces characters in a string with their [percent-encoded counterpart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), which is why a space character becomes `%20` (20 is the ASCII character code for space). It does not replace spaces with dashes.

To replace a character with another character in a string, use `String#tr`:

```
title = "Coffee Title"
title_with_dashes = title.tr(" ", "-")
puts title_with_dashes
# => Coffee-Title
```

However, this is only half of the equation. You've changed the URLs in your links but as a consequence your server probably isn't going to recognize the URL when someone clicks on the link, because the path that exists is `Coffee Title`, not `Coffee-Title`. That's a topic for another question, though.